# Dynamic Dropdown unable to sort alphabetically

Tags: c#, asp.net, alphabetical, cascadingdropdown

I have created 2 dropdown lists, the second feeds off the first. I would like the results of the second to show alphabetically, but, even though I have included an ORDER BY in my SQL, the list is not producing a sorted list.

```
  <div class="auto-style17">
            Please select the category of activity you are reviewing from the pick list :&nbsp; 
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="iSAMS" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iSAMSConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [blnActive], [TblActivityManagerFolderID], [txtName] FROM [TblActivityManagerFolder] WHERE ([intActivity] = @intActivity)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="34" Name="intActivity" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>                     

    <asp:DropDownList ID="CategorySelect" runat="server" DataTextField="txtName" DataValueField="TblActivityManagerFolderID" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ActivitySelect_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="newStyle1" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CategorySelect" 
                ErrorMessage="Please select your answer" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000; font-size: medium;">!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>

       <br />
         <div class="auto-style20">
            Please select the activity undertaken from the pick list:&nbsp; 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ActivitySelect" runat="server" DataTextField="txtName" DataValueField="TblActivityManagerGroupId" CssClass="newStyle1" AutoPostBack="True">
    </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ActivitySelect" 
                ErrorMessage="Please select your answer" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700; color: #FF0000; font-size: medium;">!</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="iSAMSActivity" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iSAMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT txtName, intActivity, intFolder, TblActivityManagerGroupId FROM TblActivityManagerGroup WHERE (intFolder = @intFolder) ORDER BY txtName ASC">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CategorySelect" Name="intFolder" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>                    
            </div>
            <div class="auto-style19">
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work - please bear in mind I am very new to C#, this is my first project so I am learning as I go so I am not great in knowing where to place coded solutions.

Here is the code behind:

```
 protected void ActivitySelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActivitySelect.Items.Clear();
    ActivitySelect.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Activity--", ""));

    ActivitySelect.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
        .ConnectionStrings["iSAMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    String strQuery = "select txtName, TblActivityManagerGroupID from dbo.TblActivityManagerGroup " +
                       "where intFolder=@intFolder";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intFolder",
        CategorySelect.SelectedItem.Value);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        ActivitySelect.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ActivitySelect.DataTextField = "txtName";
        ActivitySelect.DataValueField = "TblActivityManagerGroupID";
        ActivitySelect.DataBind();
        if (ActivitySelect.Items.Count > 1)
        {
            ActivitySelect.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivitySelect.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The shown DropDownList doesn't have a DataSourceID attribute to link it to the shown SqlDataSource???

Comment: You need to write "ORDER BY txtname asc" in sql query

Comment: @MandarDhadve I have added in asc, but this has not made a difference to the outcome.

Comment: @NineBerry the DataSource ID is applied to the top dropdown list as this is a cascading parameter. The dropdowns are producing the right fields, just not listed alphabetically. I would assume it wouldn't bring anything back if this also needed the DataSource declared??

Comment: Show the full source code or better yet create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NineBerry I have now added the code for the top dropdown

Comment: There is nothing in there which links the DropDownLists with the SQLDataSources. I suppose this happens in the actual c# code. For example, what happens in ActivitySelect_SelectedIndexChanged()?

Comment: @NineBerry I have now added the code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, the `SqlDataSource` declared in the markup is not used at all, but the query is created from the code behind. You have to change the SQL statement in the `ActivitySelect_SelectedIndexChanged()` method in the code behind:

```
String strQuery = "select txtName, TblActivityManagerGroupID from dbo.TblActivityManagerGroup " +
   "where intFolder=@intFolder order by txtName ";
```

Alternatively, change the code to actually use the `SqlDataSource` from the markup by using the `DataSourceID` attribute on the `DropDownList` to link to the correct `SqlDataSource`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added to the code behind and all is good.